# Does the tangent line between two points on a curve still exist if there's a hole on the curve?

Tags: linear-algebra

For instance, let's say the average rate of change between x=-6 and x=-3 for function $f(x) = (3x-2)(x+5) / (x+5)(x+1) = (3x-2) / (x+1)$ where x cannot equal 5 is 0.5. What about the discontinuity at x = 5? Does that do anything to the average rate of change?

Comment: do you mean discontinuity at x=-1 ?

Comment: Please, rewrite formulae with [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), so we can really understand them

Answer (score 0):

the rate of change between $x=-6$ and $x=-4$ is given by

$\Delta=\frac{f(-3)-f(-6)}{-3-(-6)}$

$=\frac{\frac{3}{2}  }{  3 }=0.5$